array offset error in VanTam PHP version 7.3
We are using VanTam builder in WordPress and just started getting this error in the blog module:
'Trying to access array offset on value of type bool (folder path) line 48'

Here is that block of code from the folder.
    if ( isset( $vamtam_theme['header-logo-type'] ) && 'image' === 
    $vamtam_theme['header-logo-type'] ) {
        echo '<div itemprop="logo" itemscope 
    itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">';
        echo '<meta itemprop="url" content="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
    get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' )[0] ) . '">';
        echo '</div>';
    }

line 48 is this line specifically:
echo '<meta itemprop="url" content="' . esc_url( wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' )[0] ) . '">';

We have no idea why or how this is happening as we are not on php v8 but we are in PHP 7.3. I see other posts with similar error but they're all custom to those project. And my PHP skills are 0.
